# Directionable parallel in parallel out register

Tags: vhdl, bus, register

I have this problem. I have 3 devices that use 4bit PIPO registers to transfer each other data. I need to make the controller that select with device to use, so it will connect A with B, AC, BA, BC, CA, CB. The thing is I don't know if I should use a Mux or a Demux or another logic interface? Any ideas how to start? I have to make it in VHDL as well, but I think that will be more easy once I know how to make the circuit.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to think of this is that each input has a 4-bit multiplexer that can choose from each of the outputs. So you have 3 4-bit MUXes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [4-Bit Wide 2:1 MUX](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=m793pb) between each two 4bit PIPO registers.